# Is "Show off" here in an imperative mood or something else?

Tags: imperatives, listening

In this [movie clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r9XkYA-ReFU), there's this conversation between Monkey and Beetle, starting at 50 seconds into the clip:

> Monkey: What?
>
> Beetle: Well, fast learner. Did you know you could do that?
>
> Monkey: Show off.

The context is that while Monkey and Beetle were arguing, Kubo made a boat.

What did Monkey mean by "Show off"?

If interpreted as an imperative mood, it doesn't really make sense to me.

If it's not, what is it?

Comment: He is calling the other a "show-off", in other words, _making a deliberate and pretentious display of talent_.

Comment: @Cascabel Thank you. Then, should it be in one word "show-off"? Also, is it a short form of "You're a show-off"?

Comment: It's being used as an adjective or noun (take your pick).  It's not a verb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**show-off** - a person who tries to impress other people with his or her abilities or possessions [Merriam-Webster]

Typical usage here is for humor. It invites the audience to interpret Monkey has saying, "yes, you made a boat, and it's very good and I'm jealous that you could do it so fast and you know it, so I'm just going to call you a name".

Answer (score 0):

Think of it like this:

> Monkey: What?
>
> Beetle: Well, fast learner. Did you know you could do that?
>
> Monkey: (You/they are a) show off.

Comment: If it's "they are a show-off", who's "they" here?

Comment: @listennever The person who did something that requires extreme talent.